# Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture

Tags: android, bitmap, textures

I've in drawable directory an image file with the 960x1440 size.
When the app start, the image is not loaded as background and in the logcat I see:

**Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2880x4320, max=4096x4096)**

Why it says 2880x4320 if the image is 960x1440 ?

The bitmap is loaded via xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/launcher_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
```

Comment: Please provide some example code, where you load the texture.

Comment: did you checked all your drawable folders if there isn't a to big file in them? Your app is working without the background image? What kind of image file is that, png, jpg?

Comment: I've only 1 file for all resolution (in drawable) of 1.02 mb and with  960x1440 size... yes, the app runs without the bg image... but not on all devices, only on Nexus 5 at the moment

Comment: I don't believe this, sorry ;) Espacilly you saying that it only runs on an nexus 5, I think your other test device are older right? The message says something about texture which indicates opengl engine of the soc, which has different limits on different devices and socs.

Comment: only on Nexus 5 it doesn't load the image...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

an image in the `/drawable/` folder without any specification is considered to be the "default", that is for 1dp = 1px that is `mpdi`, then because the device you're actually running is `xxhdpi` that image get's scaled up during runtime.

The original image might be 960x1440, but the conversion from `mdpi` to `xxhdpi` is 3 times the size, so your 960x1440 becomes (3*960)x(3*1440) = 2880x4320, which is too large of a texture to apply to the hardware accelerated views.

so to fix that is actually pretty simple, you have two choices:

1. move your image to `/drawable-nodpi/` that's simple, reduces the .apk size, but lower end devices might struggle to load such a big image.
2. create scaled images on all densities `mdpi`, `hdpi`, `xhdpi`, `xxhdpi` to avoid runtime over-scaling and to have smaller images on older devices.

Comment: actually no 2. is now pretty simple, thanks to Android Drawable Importer plugin