# How to scale android background image on all devices?

Tags: android, android-studio, photoshop

I currently have a 720x1280 pixels image as a background of an app. My image is in the drawable folder and I'm using this to scale it  `android:scaleType="fitXY`. It is working perfectly fine on my Note3, but when I'm trying it on a galaxy nexus it crashes a lot of things. The error that I'm getting is "bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture". I understood the problem because it is explained in here 
 [Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28346407/bitmap-too-large-to-be-uploaded-into-a-texture) .

I want to do one of the following things:

1. Create a resolution for every dpi folder. I have my image in photoshop as a project but I don't know how to scale it. I tried to find something but I couldn't.
2. Put it in the no-dpi folder(like that link says), a folder that for some reason doesn't appear in my app. I just have mipmap-hdpi/mdpi/xhdpi/xxhdpi. I also found this

Edit: I created the folder now

```
`nodpi - Resources for all densities. These are density-independent resources. The system does not scale resources tagged with this qualifier, regardless of the current screen's density.`
```

I would be happy with any option that might solve this problem, but the second thing might not be appropriate because it will take extra time on older devices.

Edit:

I tried the second option, but as what I quoted says, the image is no longer scaling. It takes only 1/3 of the screen on my note3 .

Comment: "a folder that for some reason doesn't appear in my app" -- you need to create it yourself. There are an infinite number of resource directories; they will not all exist when you create your project.

Comment: @CommonsWare should I call it no-dpi or mipmap-nodpi ?

Comment: You should call it `drawable-nodpi/`. The `mipmap-*/` directories usually are only used for launcher icons.

Comment: @CommonsWare it will work on nexus, but it won't scale on note3 anymore