# What is the difference between putting images in drawable and drawable-nodpi folder?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-image

When I put the image in `drawable` folder, I get `OutOfMemoryError` while setting the image resource, but after moving the same image to `drawable-nodpi` folder that error is resolved. How is error resolved on moving the image to `drawable-nodpi` folder?

Comment: CommonsWare pretty much answered it ,do mark it as the right answer.

Comment: here on my previous answer u can find more info about it too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28346407/bitmap-too-large-to-be-uploaded-into-a-texture/28348286#28348286

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`res/drawable/` is a legacy synonym for `res/drawable-mdpi/`, indicating that the drawables in that directory are set for `mdpi` density. If the device is running another density, those images will be downsampled (to `ldpi`) or upsampled (to anything else) to match the device density.

`res/drawable-nodpi/` says "these drawables should not be resampled for any density, but instead should be used as-is on all densities".

If you are getting an `OutOfMemoryError` that clears up when you move the image to `res/drawable-nodpi/`, that indicates two things:

1. The image is probably too large to begin with
2. Upsampling the image to a higher density failed, because there was no block of memory big enough for the larger upsampled image

Comment: FYI, res/drawable is also an appropriate place to put .xml/vector resources that have no fixed resolution.

Comment: @swooby: To be honest, I disagree. Now, courtesy of the Android tools team, we have no choice in the matter for vector drawables. However, I never put other XML resources in there. This decision by the tools team is one of the reasons why I have to keep explaining to developers the real role of `res/drawable/`.

Comment: Fair enough @CommonsWare, party on!

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for another great answer! you wrote, "I never put XML resources in the drawable folder". may I know where you put them? Thanks!

Comment: @beginner: Actually, I've kinda changed my mind on XML drawables, just to not "swim against the current" too much. `res/drawable/` is not ideal for XML drawables but it works.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the update! even if we put xml drawbles in `res/drawable-nodpi/` folder it won't make any diffrence. so yes, `res/drawable/` is standard choice and I don't see any drawback except the confusion  `res/drawable/` folder can create for some developers. Thanks!