# Understanding supporting different screen sizes relating to Images

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-imageview, android-screen-support

I still have problems with the correct view for the images in my Application. So on my first device (5,2 inches & 480 density) it looks good.

[image]

On the second device (5,5 inches & 420 density) the image doesn't fit and it shows white borders.

[image]

This is the ImageView in my layout:

```
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_image"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"   
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" 
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_topic" />
```

I placed all my Images in the drawable folder after reading this on a [Android Blog](http://www.tivix.com/blog/perfect-resource-image-size-dpi-for-any-android-de/):

> There are commonly two ways to target all screen DPIs.
>   1. Easiest way - Make all images to Extra High or Extra Extra High DPI.
>
> Android auto-scales the drawables if the device does not match the drawable DPI. If the only drawables are created in high density, lower DPI screens will down-scale a resource to fit in a layout.

So I implemented all Images in the highest possible resolution ONCE in the drawable folder. Is it necessary to place them all in the specific folders (drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi ...)? It would mean that there will be multiple copies of my Image with always the same size.

And yes I read the official documentation of supporting multiple screens a couple times. However I have some problems understanding it.

Comment: The problem is that the height:width ratio is changing with different screens. You need your image to always fill the space. So either fill it using the different `scaleType`, or use `gravity` for both the image view and the layout next to it so the width is always filled.

Comment: Be careful on using just 1 big image, instead of cutting to the density specific sizes, or else this can happen to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28346407/bitmap-too-large-to-be-uploaded-into-a-texture/28348286#28348286

Comment: Hardcoding sizes like this is also error-prone. Look further on using the `dimens.xml` file

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use the layout_weight attribute to keep the constant ratio between the ImageView and the question layout. 
Change your layout to something like this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="4">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm using RelativeLayout where I cannot use layout_weight

Comment: Yes, I understand, but I don't think it would be much effort to change it to LinearLayout, as there is no other way to set the ratio in the XML.