# where to put drawable image for specific screen size

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an imageview that is like this

```
 <ImageView 
 android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:src = "@drawable/myimage"/>
```

the image file "myimage.png" is in all the 4 drawable folders for different densities. The view looks good on phone. If I display it on tablet (say 10inch) then the image "looks" too small because there is so much space.

I know I can create layout for it for large screen size, but where do I place the image file with the bigger size? This way the image file can be picked based on not only density but also screen size

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `sw` notation.

For example:

```
layout/activity_with_photo.xml
layout-sw600dp/activity_with_photo.xml // that's a 7 inch tablet
layout-sw720dp/activity_with_photo.xml // that's a nexus 9 and up
```

and then the bigger images for those layout

```
// here a 7 inch tabled with all the densities
layout-mdpi-sw600dp/photo.png
layout-hdpi-sw600dp/photo.png
layout-xdpi-sw600dp/photo.png
layout-xxdpi-sw600dp/photo.png

// here a nexus 9 n up with all densities
layout-mdpi-sw720dp/photo.png
layout-hdpi-sw720dp/photo.png
layout-xdpi-sw270dp/photo.png
layout-xxdpi-sw720dp/photo.png
```

alternatively, if you're doing appropriate scaling of those resources during runtime, you could add to a `no-dpi` folder

```
layout-nodpi-sw600dp/photo.png
layout-nodpi-sw270dp/photo.png
```

but, if you're using only one, be aware of this here: [Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28346407/bitmap-too-large-to-be-uploaded-into-a-texture/28348286#28348286)

Answer (score 0):

Screen-size specific resources are denoted by `small`, `medium`, `large` and `xlarge`. So you need a `drawable-small` and/or `layout-small` folder etc.

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

EDIT: SCREEN SIZE FOLDERS ARE DEPRECATED since Android 3.2. Please use the density folders

Comment: oh I didn't know you can use the screen size as well for drawable name. So if you have image in drawable-small and drawable-xdpi  then in  a small xdpi screen, from which folder is it getting the image from?

Comment: I've just noticed that these are deprecated. Please use the density folders

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Steps: -**

1. If you are using stock icons. Go to this site https://material.io/icons/ . Select and download the icon with a size of 48dp.
2. Extract the zip file and select all the folders under android and copy them into the res folder of your project. That's it.

[image]

Comment: I am not asking about densities. I am asking about screen sizes

Comment: Go to res> values> add new file naming 'dimens'> select 'Size' in qualifiers and choose 'screen size' from small to x-large. Then add your large screen dimens under new (x-large) dimens file.

Answer (score 0):

a tricky way is set scaleType of imageView to fitcenter and set constant width and height to your imageview. it will scale up your icon to specified width and height

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/my_photo"/>
```